# Carbon: diffForHumans() displaying wrong statement

Tags: php, laravel, date, timestamp, php-carbon

I record some data in the program and it catches the date time requested. Using `Carbon::now();`

It was 8:52pm in my country (Philippines) when I store the data.

In my database , it's `2016-11-24 20:52:15`

Using Carbon formatting:

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($log->dateRequest)->format('M d, Y  - H:i:s') }} ( {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($log->dateRequest)->diffForHumans() }} )
```

The output is : `Nov 24, 2016 - 20:52:15` ( 7 hours from now )

That is the problem, it should be (8 minutes ago) if I open the log view at 9:00pm.

PS. There are also from USA who need to view the logs.

Comment: What is the timezone configured on the server and app?

Comment: 'timezone' => 'UTC',

Answer (score 3):

Try to set correct timezone in `config/app.php`:

```
'timezone' => 'Asia/Manila',
```

Comment: yea, it's working on my localhost machine. But we have people from USA who need to view the logs. Maybe it will also display a wrong statement for them.

Comment: @VahnMarty you want to read about timezones then. Here's [Carbon docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) with a lot of examples. I hope this will help.